# BigCommerce add preview code to the query string

Tags: bigcommerce

Before I launch a store, the landing page of a store contains a form

```
Coming Soon
This store will be launching shortly.
Please visit again!
Preview Code ** input **
** submit **
```

Can I add the preview code to a the querystring to automatically bypass this form?

I'm trying to test the JWT customer login feature with /login/token/{jwt}... but in practice it's just showing the coming-soon form.

Answer (score 1):

There is a query string that will bypass the Coming Soon page. If you click the View Store link from the control panel, the store URL will have a query like this appended:

/?ctk=6HLAHQ262GVC3RTZ83F5820

You can use that query string to go straight to the storefront when a store is in Coming Soon mode.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.https://store-{storeHash}.mybigcommerce.com/login/token/{token}?ctk={previewCode}. It does bypass the preview page, and displays an error of "Invalid login. Please attempt to log in again."

Comment: Sounds like that may be a different issue. The token has a very short expiration, so the access point URL will need to be visited within about 30 seconds of when the token is generated. The token URL can also only be visited once. Aside from those troubleshooting points, have you tried running your token through the debugger at jwt.io to make sure it's valid?